# Restrictions on MAC Addresses

Tags: networking, network-protocols, mac-address

I programmed a MAC address generator quite a while ago and I've lost the source code. While I programmed it, I distinctly remember that there were certain rules that needed to be followed to generate a MAC address, but I can't find them.

I think it was something like the second character needs to be 0 or something along those lines.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first *bit* needs to be zero for a unicast address. For a multicast address, that bit must be 1.

Comment: Thank you. You saved me quite a bit of confusion.